# Why isn't GIN index being used for JSONB exact match on text?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ginner ON public.documents USING gin (data)
```

And "explaining" this query:

```
select * from public.documents d where data::json->>'name' = 'Barbara Fritsch'
```

...shows:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..106065.12 rows=5002 width=725)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on documents d  (cost=0.00..104564.93 rows=2084 width=725)
        Filter: (((data)::json ->> 'name'::text) = 'Barbara Fritsch'::text)
```

Why isn't the GIN index being used?

Comment: The docs list the supported operators for the index method, and ->> is not one of them.  And certainly not when applied to the wrong type--why would you cast your jsonb (if that is what it is) to something less capable?

Answer (score 0):

GIN indexes don't support the dereference operator `->>`.

If you want to index that expression, create a regular B-tree index on it.

But you can use the GIN index if you rewrite the condition to

```
WHERE data @> '{"name": "Barbara Fritsch"}'
```